# How can you have two records with the same field names?

Tags: json, haskell, template-haskell

I'm writing a JSON service for JIRA, and I've come across a requirement that conflicts with Haskell's namespace.
I have this record

```
data Assignee = Assignee {name :: Text} deriving Generic
instance ToJSON Assignee
```

This is dictated by what JIRA wants, unfortunately it wants the same field for a different object.

```
data Reporter = Reporter {name :: Text} deriving Generic
instance ToJSON Reporter
```

I see a few options:

1. Maybe I can circumvent the compiler's complaining with template Haskell, but how?
2. I could simply not have a Reporter record, and change the reporter field with a seperate service after the ticket has been created. That I know how to do, but is it the best way?
3. Create the JSON object by hand, but I form it from this record:

   ```
     data Fields = Fields 
             { project     :: HashMap Key Project
             , summary     :: Text
             , issuetype   :: HashMap Name Task
             , versions    :: [HashMap Name Text]
             , description :: Text
             , assignee    :: Assignee
             } deriving (Generic)
   ```

The thought of making this by hand gives me the wiggins. If I must I will.

So, my question now is, if there is no other better way than the ones I've presented, which of these is the best course of action?

Comment: Maybe you can write them in different modules and don't import the `name` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to enable the `-XDisambiguateRecordFields` extension.

Answer (score 5):

If `DisambiguateRecordFields` and/or keeping the records in separate modules works for you, that's excellent.

If not, then a common way to work around this problem is to prefix record field labels in some way, to disambiguate:

```
data Assignee = Assignee {assigneeName :: Text} deriving Generic
data Reporter = Reporter {reporterName :: Text} deriving Generic
```

You can still use GHC Generics to derive the JSON translation functions, but you have to configure it so that the field labels are changed, for example like this:

```
stripPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
stripPrefix p x = case splitAt (length p) x of
  (y, z)
    | y == p    -> z
    | otherwise -> x

lower :: String -> String
lower []       = []
lower (x : xs) = toLower x : xs

stripPrefixOptions :: String -> Options
stripPrefixOptions p = defaultOptions {
  fieldLabelModifier = lower . stripPrefix p
}
```

Then you can say:

```
data Assignee = Assignee {assigneeName :: Text} deriving Generic
instance ToJSON Assignee where
  toJSON = genericToJSON (stripPrefixOptions "assignee")

data Reporter = Reporter {reporterName :: Text} deriving Generic
instance ToJSON Reporter where
  toJSON = genericToJSON (stripPrefixOptions "reporter")
```

Testing in GHCi:

```
GHCi> > encode (Assignee { assigneeName = "foo" })
"{\"name\":\"foo\"}"
```